# ssh force tty return extra non-printable character

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, tty

I know `^M` will show up when `ssh -t`, [ref1](https://serverfault.com/questions/593399/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-allocating-a-terminal-in-ssh), but I don't catch the situation when `ssh -t` into Centos 7.2(even Centos 6.2 is OK, but no difference between their environment vars). Anyone know about this? Or maybe related to [ref2](https://superuser.com/questions/629404/solaris-ssh-tt-with-no-output)?

```
$ ssh -t centos72 'echo $HOME' 2>/dev/null|cat -A
^[[?25h^[[0G^[[K^[[?25h^[[0G^[[K/home/user^M$
$ ssh centos72 'echo $HOME' 2>/dev/null|cat -A
/home/user$
$ ssh -t ubuntu1404 'echo $HOME' 2>/dev/null|cat -A
/home/user^M$
$ ssh ubuntu1404 'echo $HOME' 2>/dev/null|cat -A
/home/user$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are control characters for your terminal or VT100 codes. They are needed to make your terminal working with the remote psoudoterminal, to show your prompt and other stuff.

Verbose description of the tags from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011478/ansi-questions-x1b25h-and-x1be) and from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

- `CSI ?25h` : Shows the cursor.
- `CSI n G` : Moves the cursor to column `n`. (not ANSI.SYS)
- `CSI n K` : Erases part of the line. If n is zero (or missing), clear from cursor to the end of the line. If n is one, clear from cursor to beginning of the line. If n is two, clear entire line. Cursor position does not change.
- and once more the first two.
- `^M` : Carriage Return (on the end of the line)

These are some basic sanity checks to make sure the terminal is ready. Ubuntu sends them probably only after the query from the local terminal.

Comment: So, there is no way to disable this except for turning -t off? Why is there differences between CentOS 6.2 and CentOS 7.2?

Comment: I don't think so. Using `-T` will disable TTY allocation and therefore the control characters. If you need just the output from command, there is no reason to create remote TTY. To find a difference it would be probably required to have a look into the source code or so. I don't have CentOS machine around here (6.2 is pretty out-dated).

Comment: here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v1.9.4-1/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py#L1293 will return invalid temp path, and https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v1.9.4-1/lib/ansible/runner/connection_plugins/ssh.py#L271 will add `-tt` when in_data is None .

Comment: I have filed an issue here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13677

Comment: It might be even problem in CentOS, but I am wondering that nobody even experienced it. I just booted my RHEL7 and I don't see the problem you describe. It prints me only the `^M`, so it will be probably configuration issue. Can you check if this happen even with different users or what is in your startup scripts?

Comment: Yes, it's weird. I tried root and another regular use, it's OK. I will close the issue and investigate it.